# How to get any column of any row of a Table in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Suppose there is Table with variable number of rows of fixed number of columns, and suppose each row has a button too, now I want to select for example a column's value(let's say this selected column is textarea, so I select it's content) when that row's button is clicked.[image]

For example in above image I want that if submit is pressed than all data of 'textarea' of corresponding row should be stored in a variable.

Comment: So attach an event handler to the `button` elements and use DOM traversal to find the related `textarea`. Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `closest()` function to find an element near the clicked button.  Add click handlers to the buttons and then traverse up to find the `textarea`.

```
$('.button').on("click",function(){
    var thisRowsTA = $(this).closest("textarea");
    console.log($(thisRowsTA).val());
});
```

Comment: I did `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button1").click(function(){
  var thisRowsTA = $(this).closest('#hiii').find('textarea');
  alert($(thisRowsTA).val());
 }); });` but since i have multiple 'button' and 'textbutton' with same name.. so it only works for first button. can u tell why not for others ?

Comment: That's because you're using ids, you need to use classes like I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

A simply way is to:

Put an ID pattern to your textareas, like: txt_area_1, txt_area_2, txt_area_3.
Then, on the Click Event of your buttons, make them catch the corresponding textarea in their row. Use the ID patterns to do this.

Post your code for further help.

Comment: well if i do so and i click a button how to match a button with its corresponding textarea ?(see image)

Comment: you can put an ID pattern on your buttons too, and use it to find its corresponding textarea. But if you generate this table dynamically, just use the row number (eg.: txt_area_#rownumber#) to create the textareas IDs and in the click function of button on that row. As @O_Z answered, don't rely on DOM structure, as it may change. rely on Unique IDs.

Comment: yeah, but when a button is clicked how will i know its '#rownumber' ?

Comment: through its ID: $("#btn_#rownumber#").click(function(){ alert( $("#txt_area_#rownumber#").val()) });

Comment: oh.. but in that case we need to create many such codes.. and we don't know how much rows we have in total. Right ?

Comment: if you generate this dynamically, should not be a problem. There's others ways to this this using only one line of jquery of entire table, no matter how much rows it have, like using class on button to attach the click event on it, and the id attribute to store the row number: 

$(".btn").click(function(){ alert( $("#txt_area_"+#put here the id of button#).val()) });  If you use button_#rownumber# as id of button, you should replace/remove the "button_" to get only the number, and make a concatenation on the select of text area

Comment: yeah that will work after writing a bit of code but 'closest', 'find' in jquery do great job. :)

Comment: of course it does. but, if for some reason your DOM structure changes, and the button became far for its corresponding textarea, and others textareas became close of it, you broke your code. using ID its a little more complicated, but much more flexible and confident.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ad an event handler for each button. Inside of that you can write something like this.

```
function eventHandler(e){
    var row = this; // start at the button

    while(row.nodeName != 'TR' && row.parent){
        // go up till we find the row
        row = row.parent;
    } 


    var textArea = row.querySelector('textarea');
    var value = textArea.value; 
    // do something with supplied feedback.
}
```

In order to attach the handlers, you would do something like this.

```
function attachTableEvents(){
    var table = document.querySelector('table'); // or more specific selector if needed
    var buttons = table.querySelectorAll('button');
    for (var i = buttons.length; i--;){
        buttons[i].addEventListener(eventHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting on the DOM structure is really BAD.

I would put an attribute in my controls that holds the line number. Then when clicking an element you can easily query the DOM by element type and the property value to get any elements in this line.

Later if you change to `DIV`s or change structure your will still run correctly